# Import CSV files to mongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to import a CSV file to MongoDB following this command :

```
mongoimport -d example -c Transportation --type csv --fieldFile cyclingnetwork.csv
```

But I got this error :

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement @<shell>:1:15
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because you are trying to use the command in the `mongoshell`

You have to use `mongoimport` OUTSIDE the `mongoshell` environment.

So just turn `cmd` on if you are on windows or `terminal` if you are on mac/linux and try the same command. If you have provided the right path, it should work.